# Reference to a cons cell

Tags: reference, lisp, common-lisp, cons

How can I set a variable to point to a list cell?

I am trying to write a macro to multiply all the values in a list by a value. This is what I currently have:

```
(defmacro scale (areas scale)
  `(dotimes (n (list-length ,areas))
     (setf (nth n ,areas) (* (nth n ,areas) ,scale))))
```

I am worried that this is not the most efficient way to do things as I look up the nth cell twice. I would rather set a variable to point to the nth cell such that `setf` can modify the value of that cell and `*` can use the value of that cell in it's calculations.

Even better would be to use `dolist` and have that set the variable to the cell reference. Is this at all possible?

Whilst I'm here, is it also possible to get the next cell in the list when you have one cell. Sort of like an iterator, such that I can do something like:

```
(let ((area (car areas))
  (loop while area do
    (setf area (* area scale))
    (setf area (next area))))
```

But I don't know how it would differentiate between setting the pointer or setting the value of the referenced cell.

I hope I've made sense :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Main problem of the first code example is not that it finds `nth` cell
twice, but that it does use `nth` at all. Instead of getting the `nth`
cell, get the *next* cell which is the `cdr` of a previous cell.

You don't need a macro for that, so let's implement a function. There
is a number of ways to do things on each cons cell of a list:

```
(defun scale (areas scale)
  (do ((tail areas (cdr tail)))
      ((endp tail))
      (setf (car tail)
            (* (car tail) scale))))

(defun scale (areas scale)
  (loop for tail on areas
        do (setf (car tail)
                 (* (car tail) scale))))

(defun scale (areas scale)
  (mapl (lambda (cell)
          (setf (car cell)
                (* (car cell) scale)))
        areas))
```

There is an alternative not involving explicit operations on `car` of
each cell:

```
(defun scale (areas scale)
  (map-into areas
            (lambda (area)
              (* area scale))
            areas))
```

As a bonus, here is a `dolist`-like macro making the modifications of
"variable" in a body propagate into the list:

```
(defmacro dolistref ((var list &optional result) &body body)
  (let ((tail (gensym "TAIL"))
        (head (gensym "HEAD")))
    `(let ((,head ,list))
       (symbol-macrolet ((,var (car ,tail)))
         (do ((,tail ,head (cdr ,tail)))
             ((endp ,tail) ,result)
           ,@body)))))

;; usage example
(let ((a (list 1 2 3)))
  (dolistref (item a a)
    (incf item))) ;; => (2 3 4)
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there must be a way to get the next cell. It didn't click that it would be `cdr` of the cell but that makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Nice use of symbol-macrolet